# Cross-domain http relay server?

Tags: apache, http, vpn

I have a HTTP server(A) behind NATs, and another server(B) to be a relay node, and a random device with browser(C).

To communicate between A and B, there will be a VPN.

C is a random device(maybe IPAD, Win, Linux...), so we don't want to use VPN here.

This is the structure:

A(VPN 10.0.0.200) <------->(VPN 10.0.0.1) B (WAN 220.220.220.220) <--------->(WAN 140.140.140.140) C

and the scenario might as following:

Type "220.220.220.220:9999" on IE, B assign and relay the incoming data of 9999 to 10.0.0.200:80 (C), and C reply through the same path, then we can browse A with any device anywhere.

Is this scenario possible and how should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand right, you (C) want to connect A and B with vpn and make a request to A and A should forward this request to B and return the result to you(C)
if this is the scenario,

you may use squid on A, since A has two ip adresses, when you make a request to a.a.a.a it'll use b.b.b.x and talk to b.b.b.b

```
C (c.c.c.c) --> (a.a.a.a) A (b.b.b.x)(some ip with B's lan) <----VPN-----> B (b.b.b.b)
```